# Are there any command line swf packing tools?

Tags: flash, swf

I want to packing image files(png, jpg) into swf, then game can load files easily. But I want to do this by a Makefile, not FLASH CS.
Do you know any command line swf tool set can do that? And can I packing XML files into it as well?

Comment: Have a look at Flex, I guess http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides SWFMill, there's also [Sam HaXe](http://www.mindless-labs.com/trac/samhaxe/). Haven't used it (yet), but I ran into some obscure problems with SWFMill at some point so I'll be trying SamHaXe in the near future instead. According to the documentation, you can embed arbitrary (binary) files with optional zlib compression, so embedding xml files shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

[Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK) has support for command-line compilations because it is a compiler.
And then you could be interested also in Mike Chambers [Flash Command](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/index.php?s=FlashCommand+)

Answer (score 3):

[SWFMill](http://swfmill.org/) is the tool to use.

And you might also be interested in developing with [Haxe](http://haxe.org/).

Comment: +1. A quick question: Can I pack a xml file (e.g foo.xml) into a swf by SWFMill?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this quite a lot using the standard Flex SDK.  With a bit of python or something else you can even generate some nice class stubs to improve your work flow with the end product.